# keyboard arrow while taking input with `getline()`

Tags: c, terminal

how can I use the keyboard arrow while taking input in c instead of showing this `^[[D`

I watched a lot of videos but they were reading just 1 char with `getch` but I want to take a whole string

```
enter your equation: 2 + 1^[[D
```

so like I want to enter 1 + 1 but by mistake i entered 2 + 1 so i want to get back

```c
char *handle_input(ssize_t *nread)
{
    char *raw = NULL, *tmp = NULL;
    size_t line_len = 0;
    if (isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
        printf("enter your equation: ");
    *nread = getline(&raw, &line_len, stdin);
    if (*nread == EOF)
    {
        free(raw);
        return (strdup("dinamow done"));
    }
    if (*nread < 4)
    {
        free(raw);
        return (strdup("help"));
    }
    (raw)[*nread - 1] = '\0';
    tmp = get_string_copy(raw);
    free(raw);
    if (!strcmp(tmp, "exit"))
    {
        free(tmp);
        return (strdup("dinamow done"));
    }
    if (!strcmp(tmp, "--help") || !strcmp(tmp, "--h"))
    {
        free(tmp);
        return (strdup("help"));
    }
    return (tmp);
}
```

Comment: You need to use a library like `readline`. The terminal driver doesn't support arrow keys by itself.

Comment: `(raw)[*nread - 1] = '\0';` is wrong - the input line from `getline()` is not guaranteed to end with a `'\n'` character - for example, reading from a redirected file that doesn't end with a `'\n'` character, or entering `ctrl-Z` to close the stream.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input